# why has taken in my example?

Tags: present-perfect

I know this is an old question but it is not clear in my head

As I buy many records from Australia, I have an Australian friend who collects all the records bought there (I live in France) Today I received an email from my friend, he wanted to know if he could send them now (as he had a lot of). I answered "yes" and wrote:

I hope it has not been taking/ has taken too much of your spare time."

I asked this question to a native English and he answered"has taken" was better but I did not and still don't  understand his answer.
For me as long as the records are not sent they are still in his possession and the action of taking too much of his spare time is ongoing. It is ongoing until the records are sent: so continuous should be better .

Comment: Your reasoning is not unsound (sorry for the double negative). Once the records have been sent, the simple past becomes the tense to use: “I hope it didn’t take too much of your spare time.” But here, *hasn’t taken* has the sense of “so far” or “up to this point.”  *Hasn’t been taking* just isn’t idiomatic, though I can’t put my finger on why. Let’s see how others answer…

Comment: Presumably most of the effort is already done, and you're thanking him for that effort, so perfect is fine. If there is substantial further effort in the near future, then you might be better to use present tense ("I hope it does not take too much of your spare time") or present continuous if it's ongoing.

Comment: To my ear (Australian) *hasn’t been taking **up** too much of your spare time* would probably be most natural if the task of collecting is still ongoing. I would use *hasn’t taken up* if the task was paused or recently completed, or *didn’t take up* if it was definitely finished.

Comment: So you mean completed sent in my example ?As long as the records are still in my friend's posession we  can use continuous if we add up?

Comment: As a British English speaker I agree with Peter.

Comment: So unless it has been sent I can use the continuous? It is not very clear in your answers